# I am trying to create a partial Grayscale image

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am trying to create a partial gray scale image in which i am reading each and every pixel in that image and replacing the pixel data to gray color, and if the pixel color matches the desired color i restrict it to be applied so that the specific pixel color doesn't change.i don't know where i am going wrong it changes the whole image to gray scale and rotates the image 90 degrees. can some one help me out with this issue thanks in advance.

```
-(UIImage *) toPartialGrayscale{
const int RED = 1;
const int GREEN = 2;
const int BLUE = 3;

initialR=255.0;
initialG=0.0;
initialB=0.0;//218-112-214//0-191-255
float r;
float g;
float b;
tollerance=50;

// Create image rectangle with current image width/height
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImageView.image.size.width * scale, originalImageView.image.size.height * scale);

int width = imageRect.size.width;
int height = imageRect.size.height;

// the pixels will be painted to this array
uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

// clear the pixels so any transparency is preserved
memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// create a context with RGBA pixels
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace,
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// paint the bitmap to our context which will fill in the pixels array
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [originalImageView.image CGImage]);

for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        uint8_t *rgbaPixel = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y * width + x];

        // convert to grayscale using recommended method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale
        uint8_t gray = (uint8_t) ((30 * rgbaPixel[RED] + 59 * rgbaPixel[GREEN] + 11 * rgbaPixel[BLUE]) / 100);

        // set the pixels to grayi

        r= initialR-rgbaPixel[RED];
        g= initialG-rgbaPixel[GREEN];
        b= initialB-rgbaPixel[BLUE];

        if ((r<tollerance&&r>-tollerance)&&(g<tollerance&&g>-tollerance)&&(b<tollerance&&b>-tollerance))
        {
            rgbaPixel[RED] = (uint8_t)r;
            rgbaPixel[GREEN] = (uint8_t)g;
            rgbaPixel[BLUE] = (uint8_t)b;
        }
        else
        {
            rgbaPixel[RED] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[GREEN] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[BLUE] = gray;
        }


    }
}

// create a new CGImageRef from our context with the modified pixels
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

// we're done with the context, color space, and pixels
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
free(pixels);

// make a new UIImage to return
UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image
                                             scale:scale
                                       orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

// we're done with image now too
CGImageRelease(image);

return resultUIImage;
}
```

This is the code i am using any kind of help will be appreciated thanks again in advance.

Comment: some code would help to identify the error.

Comment: i have just posted my code vignesh thank you for the immediate response

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the orientation piece is easy enough to resolve by playing with the `UIImageOrientationUp` constant that you're passing in when you create the final image. Try left or right until you get what you need.

As for the threshold not working, can you verify that your "tollerance" really is behaving like you expect. Change it to 255 and see if the entire image retains it's color (it should). If it's still grey, then you know that your conditional statement is where the problem lies.

Comment: hi ryan thank you for the response, i tried replacing the "tollerance" value to 255 i get the entire image retains its color.

Comment: Awesome! then we know that everything is working, but your definition of "Red" is too restrictive to work on the images you've been testing on. There are many valid approaches to this, but one you might try is taking the Red value of the pixel and subtracting the Blue and Green from it. If the result is above some threshold, then it's "Red". There was nothing wrong with your first approach either, but you need to fine tune the definition of "Red" to be a bit more permissive regardless.

Comment: It may or may not be appropriate in your app, but you can also add a UISlider to the interface and have it set the threshold when adjusted.